# How to collect all logs from number of servers in docker swarm?

Tags: docker, logging, dockerfile, docker-swarm, filebeat

I have number of Linux server that have docker installed on them, all of the server are in a docker swarm, on each server i have a custom application. I also have ELK setup in AWS.

I want to collect all logs from my custom app to the ELK on AWS, I have successfully done that on one server with filebeat by running the following commands:
1. docker pull docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat-oss:7.3.0
2. created a file in /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml with the content:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: container
  paths:
  - '/usr/share/continer_logs/*/*.log'
  containers.ids:
  - '111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
  processors:
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["XX.YY.ZZ.TT"]
```

3. chown root:root filebeat.yml
4. sudo docker run -u root -v /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml -v /var/lib/docker/containers:/usr/share/continer_logs -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat-oss:7.3.0

And now i want to do the same on all of my docker hosts(And there are a lot of them) in the swarm.

I encounter a number of problems:
1. How do i copy "filebeat.yml" to /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml on every server?
2. How do i update the "containers.ids" on every server? and how to update it when i upgrade the docker image?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How do I copy "filebeat.yml" to /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml on every server?

You need a configuration management tool for this. I prefer [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), you might want to take a look at others.

> 2. How do I update the "containers.ids" on every server?

You don't have to. Docker manages it by itself **IF** you use swarm mode. You're using `docker run` which is meant for the development phase and to deploy applications at one single machine. You need to look at [Docker Stack](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part5/) to deploy an application across multiple servers.

> How to update it when I upgrade the docker image?

[`docker stack deploy`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/) does both, deploy and update, services.

NOTE: Your image should be present on each node of the swarm in order to get its container deployed on that node.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay, about "containers.ids" - docker update it in the "filebeat.yml"?

Comment: @polyvar I don't get your question. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I am talking about the filebeat.yml config file, there is a field named "containers.ids" that say to filebeat what container logs to take.
I need only my custom_app logs and not other containers logs

Comment: @polyvar: Instead of collecting logs of a container, can you collect the logs of a service? As far as I know, when dealing with swarm mode, we do not interact with containers individually. We interact with services.